# Matlab error: IMSHOW unable to display image

Tags: linux, matlab, remote-access, imshow

I would run Matlab on a remote server.
In my script I need to draw some rectangles on an image.
This is my code:

```
set(0,'DefaultFigureVisible','off');
figure;
imshow(img,[])
hold on
.
.
.
patch([c, c, c+N-1, c+N-1], [r, r+N-1, r+N-1, r], col, 'edgecolor', 'none', 'facecolor', col, 'facealpha', .4)
```

I get the error "IMSHOW unable to display image". I suppose it is produced by graphical problems. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It happens because I can't display the image on the server. Any ideas about how can I plot something on an image without call imshow?

Comment: True, but there has not been an answer.

Comment: You are right. Sorry!